# How to print an empty string without double quotes using awk command

Tags: shell

I m writing a shell script which will gather data from an input file and this data is stored in an output file with comma as separator. The data has mainly dates getting printed in string format. I want to print the data in the output file as follows. When there is data present, we store it in the double quotes. But when there is no data, it should not be stored in double quotes. i.e, the empty data should not be shown in double quotes.

Eg:  I have 7 fields to be printed and when there is data present in all the fields, it should print as below.

```
"T83261914N","2018-02-16","2018-01-30","2018-01-01","2018-12-31","4","Accepted"
```

Suppose in the 4th and 5th field if there is empty data it should print as below.

```
"T83261914N","2017-12-13","2017-12-12",,,"5","Accepted".
```

But the data is being printed as below for me.

```
"T83261914N","2017-12-13","2017-12-12","","","5","Accepted".
```

I dont want the double quotes in the output when there is empty data. I have tried the below code using awk command.

But still the double quotes are getting printed when there is empty data.

```
# print the columns in proper format
     awk 'BEGIN {
      FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
     }
     {  if (length($4) == 0) 
        gsub("\"","",$4);

        printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",
              $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7
     }' $InputFile > $OutputFile
```

What change can be done to this to get the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: By seeing your profile @Satyanvesh D, came to know sometimes you don't select any answer as correct one, I would like to request you, give it sometime to your question and when you see few answers, do select anyone of them as correct  too, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sure. Will go through and definitely do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has told about his sample data now, so adding solution as per that sample.

```
awk '{gsub(/\,\042\042/,",")} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"T83261914N","2017-12-13","2017-12-12",,,"5","Accepted"
```

***Explanation:*** Using `gsub` of `awk` to globally substitute `,""` with `,`(here I am using `\042` for representing `"`). Then I am using `1` to print edited/non-edited line.

---

---

Since you have shown only expected output not the sample of  Input_file, so I am assuming that your Input_file looks as follows(as an example).

```
cat Input_file
T83261914N,2017-12-13,2017-12-12,,,5,Accepted
```

Now let's run following code.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!=""){$i="\042" $i "\042"}}} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"T83261914N","2017-12-13","2017-12-12",,,"5","Accepted"
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravinder for the answer. But for me the actual input file looks like this. "T83261914N","2017-12-13","2017-12-12","","","5","Accepted".  All that i want is when empty data is present i dont want the double quotes around it in the output file. can you help with that please.

Comment: @SatyanveshD, sure, could you please try my EDIT code and let me know then?